# 403 this action is unauthorized in Laravel Policy

Tags: laravel, policy, laravel-9

**Postpolicy.php**

```
/**
     * Determine whether the user can update the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Post  $post
     * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response|bool
     */
    public function update(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        return $user->id === $post->user_id;
    }
```

**PostController.php**

```
  /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Request $request,Post $post)
    {   
        $this->authorize('update',$post);
        $id=$request->id;
        $edit=Post::find($id);
        if($edit){
        return view('editform');
        }
        return abort(404);
    }
```

I am trying to edit the post if the posts belong to logged-in users but I am getting this action is not authorized error whenever I press the edit button to get the edit form. Above are my codes and I don't know what is wrong with them. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Is your post policy filename `Postpolicy.php` or `PostPolicy.php`, and does the classname match the filename, including capitalisation?

Comment: There's also some redundant, possibly troublesome code in your example above as well. The `$id=$request->id; $edit=Post::find($id);` will load a different Post model compared to the one you're checking the policy against. Your code indicates you're using [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding), so the `Post $post` argument automatically loads the correct model, and there's no need for the additional `if($edit){` check later. And since your most recent edit, the `return view('editform');` code doesn't make sense.. why aren't you passing the `$post` data?

Comment: @Kirk Beard sorry it's PostPolicy and it does match with the file name

Comment: Can you do `dd($user->id);` and `dd($post->user_id);` in your `update()` method to double check you're getting the values you're expecting?

Comment: dd($post->user_id); is giving null value

Comment: That's why your PostPolicy returns false then. You need to ensure `return $user->id === $post->user_id;` returns true. Set the `user_id` value to the same as the `$user->id` and it'll work.